# Whats going on with the ubuntu website description?

Tags: ubuntu-website

I just went to the Ubuntu website to download the latest version of Ubuntu and noticed that the description is broken. Anyone know why its like that or if its safe to download from there?

Here's a screenshot of broken website:

[image]

Comment: The image you show doesn't seem valid; it looks to me like it says 16.04 as if this is 2016-April?  The data on your picture looks very *outdated* to me.  FYI:  I do see that detail too if I go to duckduckgo, however it's an issue with duckduckgo & not Ubuntu... Click on the link and its current detail

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not just that link its many other ubuntu links that are like that...even the latest ones... So if its just duckduckgo does that mean its safe to download from it?

Comment: Yes https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ (*where actual downloads will come from if you go through https://ubuntu.com/*) will be safe to download from; what you've found just means that details in some duckduckgo pages are out of date; that's true to pages on google.com too often

Comment: "*I just went to the Ubuntu website*" The provided image is **not** the Ubuntu website. It appears you went elsewhere. Your confusion seems self-inflicted.

Answer (score 2):

You mention "*I just went to the Ubuntu website to download*" but your image shows a https://duckduckgo.com/?t=h_&q=ubuntu&ia=web type of search enquiry, ie. details on your page are from duckduckgo and not Ubuntu

Your image shows reference to Ubuntu 16.04 or the 2016-April release; ie. a very outdated piece of data, that [release has been EOSS or *End of Standard Support* since 2021-April](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/).

What you discovered just tells you details at the *duckduckgo* search engine became stale & thus can be misleading. The same applies to *google* and all search engines.

If you want to get correct details about Ubuntu, use https://ubuntu.com/ and all details will be correct at time of visit, and all downloads from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ will be safe.

Comment: Just an FYI, but you don't need to navigate to https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ to download, as all links found at https://ubuntu.com/ and even Ubuntu *flavors* like https://lubuntu.me/downloads/  (Lubuntu being a Ubuntu *flavor* I'm involved with) will cause a download from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ as that's where **official** ISOs are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Just open https://ubuntu.com/ and download the version that you want.

As the others said, it's not an Ubuntu problem, it's search engines problem.

I am also using DuckDuckGo as my main search engine, and that's not what I am seeing when I search for `Ubuntu`. I have no idea what your settings are, but you should check them if that's your first result.

I was able to reproduce your problem by searching for `ubuntu tutorial install ubuntu desktop 16.04`. What I am seeing is, that it is really broken, but if you open the link, it's OK.

[image: duckduckgo results]

Same query looks normally in Google:

[image: google results]

On the other hand, this is also broken in Bing (DuckDuckGo partner):

[image: bing results]

It looks normally in Yandex too:

[image: Yandex results]

Comment: Thanks for the info just got the latest Ubuntu version ツ